# Twitter Bootstrap content in container not centered

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for a site. I'm trying to get the content centered. Traditionally I would simple create a custom `.container` class that looks like this:

```
.container {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've tried to override this class manually, but only the width seems to make a difference. I place the content inside the container like this:

```
<div class="container>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

The container itself is centered. But the content inside seems to have a left margin/padding. Any ideas on how I should structure my divs?

**Update** 
I use `Bootstrap v3.0.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd stick with the scaffolding here if I were you, which keeps it responsive, clean & inline with the rest of the expected Bootstrap HTML. I'll demonstrate an Bootstrap 3.0.0 example below (As you haven't mentioned an version number)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-view class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div ng-view class="col-xs-8 content">Centre</div>
        <div ng-view class="col-xs-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply Demo](http://bootply.com/104775)

Comment: `v3.0.3` shouldn't be too much different in regards of class names, so that's ok there =)

Comment: I've tried your answer - seems to work, but the content becomes quite narrow for me. Do you have any ideas on what can cause that?

Comment: because of your screen size you're working with, bootstrap uses `%`, thus it's relative to the amount of space left, you can decrease `col-xs-2` to `col-xs-1` and `col-xs-8` to `col-xs-10` to increase the content size

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.container
{
    width: 0%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything like:

```
.container > div{
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue and solved it by changing:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

to:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

and all of a sudden everything started behaving as I expected.  Not sure why using the element ng-view rather than the attribute ng-view helped, but it did!